# Как узнать ID пользователя написавшего в беседу через бота в группе на python?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне нужно узнать ID пользователя который пишет в беседу на python.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы используете CallBack api, то это делается так:

```
if data["type"] == "message_new":
    object = data["object"]  # получаем объект сообщения
    object["from_id"]  # id отправителя сообщения
```

На LongPoll это будет так:

```
event.obj.from_id  # id отправителя сообщения
```

В обоих случаях id возвращается как число

Answer (score 0):

***Вот код на получение id
и кст. в личку peer = id***

```
while True: #-цикл
for event in longpoll.listen(): #создание-переменной-event
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW: #проверка-и-отправка-смс
        peer = event.object.message['peer_id'] #id-чата
        id = event.object.message['from_id'] #id отправителя
```